# Xterm.js in UWP WebView - paste programmatically

Tags: uwp, xtermjs

I'm working on a terminal app based on Xterm.js which runs in UWP WebView. Everything works OK, and I'm able to paste any text to the terminal by using Ctrl+V - it looks that it is handled automatically by Xterm.js.

But I cannot implement "Paste" menu option. I've tried to do something like:

`var value = await _webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new []{"document.execCommand('paste')"});`

(according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) but no luck. Nothing get pasted, and the call returns empty string.

Any ideas how to implement paste from UWP app menu? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with WebView because I found it from the [github issue](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/2390) at xterm.js.

You can consider publishing a Terminal object, such as attaching it to the window object so that it can be publicly accessed from outside, then use `_webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval",new string[] { "window.term.paste("some string") "});`to paste.

If you don't want to expose the terminal object, you can wrap the paste method as a public function and then call it through `InvokeScriptAsync`.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks Richard! It does exactly what I need!